# using momentjs in angular gives me undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, momentjs

I am using angular + momentjs on my project. I also add [angular-moment](https://github.com/urish/angular-moment) library to.
Here is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alkimake/LsNtN/1/)

using moment in controller method gives me error:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at new <anonymous> (http://fiddle.jshell.net/alkimake/LsNtN/1/show/:56:23)
    at invoke (http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.1/angular.js:3624:28)
    at Object.instantiate (http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.1/angular.js:3636:23)
    at http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.1/angular.js:6639:28
    at http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.1/angular.js:6083:34
    at forEach (http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.1/angular.js:307:20)
    at nodeLinkFn (http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.1/angular.js:6070:11)
    at compositeLinkFn (http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.1/angular.js:5536:15)
    at publicLinkFn (http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.1/angular.js:5444:30)
    at http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.1/angular.js:1287:27
```

I wonder why i cant use moment in controller method or in scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the wrong methods to access the day, month & year values. Should be:

```
var sd = $scope.s.date();
var md = $scope.s.month();
var yd = $scope.s.year();
```

See [moment docs](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/date/)

Comment: i was thinking about moment gives me an error. thank you so much.